# Bring Sybase database offline

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase, isql

Is there a way to bring a database offline in Sybase ASE 16.0?

I know a database gets set offline when loading a dump, but that can't be the only way to set a database offline.

There is also an [official article](https://accounts.sap.com/saml2/idp/sso?SAMLRequest=fZJRT8IwFIX%2FytL3sW6BIA2QIMRIgriw6YNvpbuTJltbe1vUf283UPFBkj7dnHO%2B29NOkbeNYQvvDmoHbx7QRevVjBSUTmjN6308ouImTgGqeDKuRjGkwEfjbAg1H5PoGSxKrWYkG1ASrRE9rBU6rlwY0SyL0zSm4zIdsXCGkxcSrQJBKu5618E5gyxJuBDaK4cD5GYgdJt0W2WJrEyCqEl0p62AfscZqXmD0LFyjiiP8DNZIILtcpdaoW%2FBFmCPUsDTbvNL8kHDjQkkb4y27oJozlQ0YR9MKE1JlFvttNDNrVSVVK8z4q1imqNEpngLyJxgxeJhw8L92f4kQnZflnmcPxYliT7aRiHrS75uNmcSmU87Neu7tBf%2B63b%2BfXkyX%2BR5sdxsS0qzaXKRdQo2bBvM61WuGyk%2Bu2Zb7v7PTgdpP5FVXPdS5hUaELKWUIXOm0a%2FLy1wF97BWQ8kmZ%2Bgf%2F%2FU%2FAs%3D&RelayState=oucqqzqfafbovqcyoreedozxdvoereavxsuefax&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2F04%2Fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256&Signature=CfEuIrM8lSkX5YeL25cK82bwyNtkPGK1Ow%2FHBxr7DGQBTtWjT7ryb9WaGyFKlEXmeIEOIBCSpw6CJTzesgtv2GO%2BdSBpPAJcMad6JUHag5p6PbjfsSS78oVQUXk8xtAwQcv5s1uf7n%2BBDv0tSRxqx8i6hGYGoY4xXmxYJccN188%3D) for that, but it's locked behind a PayWall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBA-level direct edit of system catalog would place it into that state. Try it on a dev instance to see if this is what you were looking for in re: offline database command.

```
sp_configure 'allow updates',1
go

reconfigure with override
go

update master..sysdatabases 
set status=512 
where name='<database of interest>'
go

sp_configure 'allow updates',0
go

reconfigure with override
go
```

Other states you might look into would be:

```
512  offline 
1024 read only 
2048 dbo use only 
4096 single user
```

Some of these states can be set via the sp_dboption calls, like

```
master..sp_dboption <database of interest>, "read", true
go
```

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes to mind would be:

```
dbcc dbreboot('shutdown',<dbname1>[,<dbname2>, ...,<dbnameN>])
```

The only documentation I'm finding is this [wiki page for dbcc dbreboot()](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBASE/DBCC+dbreboot).

Keep in mind that `online database` will not make the database available again.  To make the database available you'll need to run `dbcc dbreboot('restart',<dbname>)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't really help, since I need the DB in the same state after loading a dump, so that `online database <DB>` does the job.

Comment: why not replace `online database <DB>` with `dbcc dbreboot('restart',<DB>)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the database into "dbo use only" mode, so that only the owner can access it:

```
use master
go
sp_dboption <databasename>, 'dbo use only', true
go
```

Should a non-dbo user attempt to use the database, it will result in the message:

```
User <uid> not allowed in database '<databasename>' - only the owner of this database can
access it.
```

Any logins that you have aliased to dbo in the database will still have access, though.